# Как перемешать два списка одинаково?

Tags: python, list

Это у нас до начала программы

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ['a', 'b', 'v', 'g']
```

Идет перемешивания и должно получиться:

```
a = [3, 4, 1, 2]
b = [‘v’, ‘g’, ‘a’, ‘b’]
```

как бы 1 и 2 привязаны к ‘a’ и ‘b’, также 3 и 4, к ‘v’ и ‘g’. Главное особенность, чтобы они оставались как 2 списка и работали как описано выше.

Comment: Вопрос то в чём?

Comment: если ты в гугле так же запросы делаешь как заголовки, то вряд ли вообще когда-нибудь что-нибудь найдешь

Comment: смысл всего этого действа какой?

Answer (score 0):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) -> [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) -> [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
import random

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

lst = list(zip(a, b))
random.shuffle(lst)
a, b = zip(*lst)

print(a)
print(b)
```

> ```
> $ python shuffle.py
> (1, 3, 2, 4)
> ('a', 'c', 'b', 'd')
> ```

Comment: a = [1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] Да, работает как мне надо, а вот еще вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы: 1 был привязан к ‘a’ и ‘b’, а 2 к ‘c’ и ‘d’

Comment: Как вы привяжите, так и будет перемешано. Привяжите к одному элементу `a` несколько элементов  `b`, перемешайте, соберите массивы обратно.